# Hoplon With Castra Error Loading The Backend

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, boot-clj, hoplon

I have been having a similar problem for a while. When I use the following in my 'build.boot' it doesn't load the backend until I go in and edit a backend file and then save. I was wondering how I can get it to load the backend on 'boot dev'.

```
(deftask dev
 []
 (comp
  (serve
   :port    8000
   :handler 'myapp.handler/app
   :reload  true)
  (watch)
  (hoplon)
  (reload)
  (cljs)))
```

Cheers,

:::EDIT:::
If I edit the 'index.cljs.hl' file and just remove the (rpc/init) function then save then re-insert the (rpc/init) function it seems to load the backend. I tried many things from using on page load to moving the position of the (rpc/init) in the index page. I don't quite understand why it requires editing and saving to make it work.

Comment: I really don't see how editing a cljs file could make "it seems to load the backend". Not familiar with hoplon, so this is just a guess: maybe `(rpc/init)` is not called at the right time? A simple test would be to do something like `(js/setTimeout #(rpc/init) 10000)` or even run it from the console/repl and see if that works? If yes then it is likely `rpc/init` is called too early.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is most likely a better way, but the following should work:

```
(deftask dev
 []
 (comp
  (serve
   :port    8000
   :handler 'myapp.handler/app
   :reload  true)

  ;; duplicate these
  (hoplon)
  (reload)
  (cljs)

  (watch)
  (hoplon)
  (reload)
  (cljs)))
```

You can then refactor it like so:

```
(deftask do-stuff []
 (comp
  (hoplon)
  (reload)
  (cljs)))


(deftask dev
 []
 (comp
  (serve
   :port    8000
   :handler 'myapp.handler/app
   :reload  true)
   (do-stuff) ; init
   (watch)
   (do-stuff)))
```

Comment: I tried this and I don't think it fixes the problem. As far as I can tell, it seems like the problem is getting (rpc/init) to load properly, I will try debugging some more and then post.